# Opencart - get product option quantity or stock text (option to product module)

Tags: php, sql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using Option to Product extension on my Opencart 2.0x website. It all works as expected. I want to have the stock availability of the options in the option select box. For example:

Current: 
Blue 
Red
Orange

What I want:
Blue (In Stock)
Red (In Stock)
Orange (Out of Stock)

Something like the above. So I need to either get the stock text or the quantity and then manually add the text dependant on the quantity.

I try to modify the code in view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl to be:

```
<?php 
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {  
if ($option_value['quantity'] == "0") {
$stock = "Out of Stock";
} else {
$stock = "In Stock";
}
?>
<option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?> (<?php echo $stock ?>) </option>
}
```

In catalog/controller/product/product.php after

```
'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
```

I add

```
'quantity'         => $option_value['quantity'],
```

I get nothing!

---

I have even tried to access the database directly but it doesn't work - I am not sure how to get the value I want from the database - I use

```
$product_id = $product_id;
$option_id = $option_value['option_value_id'];

$get_otp_id = $this->db->query("SELECT id from oc_otp_option_value where product_id = $product_id AND parent_option_value_id = $option_id");
```

I know I cannot add this to the product template page as it is a MVC setup but don't know how to add this to the Model and then use the Controller to get the data and show it on the View template as I am a noob with MVC and OpenCart.

Please help - I will love you forever!

Thanks

Comment: What is your OC version exactly? 2.0.0.0?

Comment: Hi @DigitCart - thanks - it is Version 2.0.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, Edit this file:

```
catalog\controller\product\product.php
```

**Find:**

```
foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
```

**Add after it:**

```
$stock_text = $option_value['quantity'] > 0 ? '(In Stock)' : '(Out Of Stock)';
```

**Find:**

```
'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
```

**Replace with:**

```
'name'                    => $option_value['name'] . $stock_text,
```

Then clear all your caches (ocmod, vqmod, ...).

Note: If an option value is out of stock, OpenCart will not display that option on the product page, unless you choose "No" to Subtract Stock.

Comment: Thanks for this. It hasn't done it, unfortunately. I edited the vqmod cache file to make sure and so that if there are any issues I can just clear the cache and all will be fine. Therefore I also know it is not a caching issue.

Did you see that I am using Option to Product extension and not the default Opencart Options? Thanks so much for the help

Comment: ok thanks. Yes I got it working with the default - however I am using Option to Ptoduct extension which doesnt use the default variant fields..

Comment: Is that a free or commercial extension?

Comment: It is a commercial extension. Dont know how I can let you know how it works or pass the code so you can see

Comment: You must contact extension developer.

Comment: I have, heard nothing :D Thanks for the help - I will carry on trying

Comment: I am doing some testing. I changed $stock_text = $option_value['quantity'] > 0 ? '(In Stock)' : '(Out Of Stock)'; to be $stock_text = "test". Just to see if it will show

It still didnt work which means there must be an issue. The product page is looking for $option_value['name'] so not sure why $option_value['name'] . $stock_text is not